# jQuery animate transform translate x,y

Tags: jquery

I need to animate an image, but I would like to use CSS transforms. I found a previous question where the solution was this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ERRmd/)

I modify it this way:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JH3r/2/)

I don't know how to pass x and y values, since I need to translate(x,y) both.

This way doesn't work:

```
$('#box').animate({  fake: [100,50] }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
       $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translate(' + now[0] + 'px,' + now[1] + 'px)'); 
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```

Comment: Why do you want to use CSS transforms?  It seems like a good way to make things complicated and less compatible with certain browsers.

Comment: because is much smoother especially in chrome

Comment: also how do you get matrix to transform options (scale, translate, rotate)

Answer (score 2):

```
;(function($) {
            var delay = 0;
            $.fn.translate3d = function(translations, speed, easing, complete) {
                var opt = $.speed(speed, easing, complete);
                opt.easing = opt.easing || 'ease';
                translations = $.extend({x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}, translations);

                return this.each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);

                    $this.css({ 
                        transitionDuration: opt.duration + 'ms',
                        transitionTimingFunction: opt.easing,
                        transform: 'translate3d(' + translations.x + 'px, ' + translations.y + 'px, ' + translations.z + 'px)'
                    });

                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        $this.css({ 
                            transitionDuration: '0s', 
                            transitionTimingFunction: 'ease'
                        });

                        opt.complete();
                    }, opt.duration + (delay || 0));
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

In this way you can use also translateZ;

source http://cameronspear.com/blog/animating-translate3d-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box').animate({  fake: 200, fake2: 10 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translate('+now+'px,'+now+'px )'); 
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asantarissy/NBM6g/)

Answer (score 1):

this way seems to work but it may exist a better solution

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hPtjf/1/)

```
var offX, offY;

$('#box').animate({  fake1: 150, fake2: 100 }, {
  step: function(now,fx) {

    if (fx.prop === "fake1") {
      offX = now;
    } else if (fx.prop === "fake2") {
      offY = now;
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translate('+ offX +'px,'+ offY +'px)');
    }
  },
  duration:300
},'linear');
```

Comment: this only works if you want to start from `0`. otherwise you have to use `$({fake1: 50, fake2: 70}).animate(...)` and switch `$(this).css(...)` to `$('#box').css(...)`